# Meaning of single + prefix in incrementation

Tags: c#, operators

I download a code which provide integer value incrementation by 5 like this:

```
int i =0;
i = +i +5;
```

I usually use:

```
i+=5;
```

Is there any difference beetwen this two form? Is it special meaning od single prefix plus?

Comment: `+i` is the same as `i`. It's optional if it's a positive number, you can use `10` or `+10`.

Comment: ... and the opposite of `-1`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator

Comment: @Rango Is it means that in general there is no reason to use +i in this case?

Comment: @ElConrado There is never a case.

Comment: that `+i` has no affect ... see this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/2hDVTJ

Comment: @ElConrado: i never saw this, but that doesn't mean that there is never a reason. In this case it doesn't make much sense apart from if the author wanted to confuse the reader

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, a hypothetical class could [override the + operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778939/overloading-unary-operators) for whatever reason and make it an essential part of its API. However, I know of no such library.

Comment: In il there is strictly the same...

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating the hypothetical class from my previous comment https://dotnetfiddle.net/zYQGSE

Comment: Then I am sorry. It does work indeed @Peping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask if there is any difference between `i = +i +5;` and `i = i + 5;`, no, there is not.

`+5` is just the same as `5`, and it is the 'opposite' of `-5`. The `+` sign is just allowed for consistency here (it would be 'weird' to be able to use the minus sign to sign a number, but not the plus sign).

Comment: In other words, - and + can function both as unary and binary operators, just like in mathematics, with the + being implicit :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases 
i = +i +5; / i=i+5
is equivalent to the 
i = i +5;

But in the i+=5, i is only evaluated once (see [+= operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator)). It may take an effect in the case of [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) variable, because of side effect.

Comment: Could you share the project you encountered with problem in?

Comment: There is no problem stated, it was just a question.

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that _"...evaluated once..."_ makes sense only in a _generic_ description of the `+=` operator. For an `int` type (as in the example) the **exact** same code (1 read, add, 1 write) is generated.

Comment: I think, if x is some special variable that could evaluated indirect or shared between few threads, it could be changed in some ambiguous way. But, if variable changed in indirect way it should be volatile.
Cite: "The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. The compiler, the runtime system, and even hardware may rearrange reads and writes to memory locations for performance reasons. "